# OnClickItem with unknown number of items Android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have an array of objects. In my listview, I pass only the name of those objects but when someone clicks on any of them, I want a new window to pop up and to see the extra information from my items. Can I do that somehow?

This is how my list activity looks like:

```
public class ListItemsActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] mTestArray;
    ListView listView;
    private static final String TAG = "ListActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create the list activitye");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
        ArrayList<Sweet> sweets = getSweets(mTestArray);
        ArrayList<String> result = getSweetsNames(mTestArray);
        Log.d(TAG, mTestArray.toString());

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_list_items,
                result;
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));

        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + mTestArray[position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So this is ok, it shows me a lsit of names. And when I click on them it jsut tells me on a small popup thing that I've selected it. What I want is actually to open a new window and show all the information from my items. Is that possible? How would I go around to do it?

The only way I found is to do something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
   switch( position ) {
     case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i1.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 1:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i2.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 2:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i3.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 3:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i4.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
     case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i5.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
              break;
    }
}
```

But it's a bad approach for these reasons: 
1) I have an unknown number of elements
2)I dont have 1000 activities for each item, I want 1 general window that would depend on some integer position.

Can I do it this way?

Comment: What information do you want to show?

Comment: I have a class called Sweets and ti has like name, price, description... right now I only show the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting position of the item from listView, then I think you can get the information about same item by the use of Adapter.

**Codes that you can try:**

1. **Make a xml that your list view items would have:**

This can include any types of items and items would be seen in the list view as you would want to show it. I am making an xml named **list_items_view.xml** and including just a text view in the listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameInList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:padding="7dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. **Make a class that would include the items that you want to bind with each list-items:**

Here I am binding each list items with it's description, price, and callories (You can change that according to your need), and make constructor and getter-setter method for each one.Name of the class is **ListDetailsClass**:

```
public class ListDetailsClass {

    String price,name, description,calories;

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ListDetailsClass(String price, String name, String description, String calories) {
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(String calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
    }
}
```

3. **Make an adapter that could adapt the properties of the xml and the class in one single item:**

Here I have made an adapter class that extends **BaseAdapter** and implemented it's methods according to use of my purpose.Name of the class is **adapterForLV**:

```
public class adapterForLV extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ListDetailsClass> itemsInList;
    Context mContext;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Context getmContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setmContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public ArrayList<ListDetailsClass> getItemsInList() {
        return itemsInList;
    }

    public void setItemsInList(ArrayList<ListDetailsClass> itemsInList) {
        this.itemsInList = itemsInList;
    }

    public adapterForLV(ArrayList<ListDetailsClass> itemsInList, Context mContext) {
        this.itemsInList = itemsInList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsInList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsInList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(inflater == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_view,null);
        }

        TextView nameOfItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameInList);

        ListDetailsClass items = itemsInList.get(position);

        String name = items.getName();

        nameOfItem.setText(items.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

4. **Finally implement adapter in your main activity so as to include the list items with bound data:**(Name of the activity is **MainActivity**)

   ```
   ListView listView;

   ArrayList<ListDetailsClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

   adapterForLV customAdapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv) ;

   //Adapted the list form with customAdapter

       customAdapter = new adapterForLV(list,this);

   //Set the listview to the customAdapter

       listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

   //Made two new objects of the ListDetaisClass to add data in the listview 

       ListDetailsClass newData = new ListDetailsClass("3$","abc","description","543 cal");
       ListDetailsClass newData2 = new ListDetailsClass("35.3$","item name","description about item","callories about it");

   //Added data to the list

       list.add(newData);
       list.add(newData2);


   //Listview item click listener implementation
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String name = customAdapter.getItemsInList().get(position).getName();
           String description = customAdapter.getItemsInList().get(position).getDescription();
           String price = customAdapter.getItemsInList().get(position).getPrice();
           String calories = customAdapter.getItemsInList().get(position).getCalories();


   //Intent to pass the data of the list item to next activity

           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
           i.putExtra("Item_Name",name);
           i.putExtra("Item_Desc",description);
           i.putExtra("Item_Price",price);
           i.putExtra("Item_cal",calories);
           startActivity(i);

       }
       });

   }
   ```
5. **Getting the data to show in the form according to our use in the new activity:**

Here you have to define a new xml for the new activity so that data could be shown in the form we want.

**Main2Activity**:

```
//defined textViews to show my data
TextView itemName,itemDescription,itemPrice,itemCal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
    itemDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemDescr);
    itemCal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemCal);
    itemPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemPrice);

//Getting data from oldActivity i.e. MainActivity
    Intent i = getIntent();

//Setting data to textViews
    itemName.setText("Name: "+i.getStringExtra("Item_Name"));
    itemDescription.setText("Description: "+i.getStringExtra("Item_Desc"));
    itemPrice.setText("Price: "+i.getStringExtra("Item_Price"));
    itemCal.setText("Calories: "+i.getStringExtra("Item_cal"));


}
```

**Screenshots after implementation**:

1. **Listview**

[image: Listview]

2. **Item details in new activity**

[image: item details]

Hope this help you!

Comment: I am getting the positon but can I push the position onto the next activity? Let's say something Intent intent=new Intent(ListItemActivity.this, newDetailActivity.class, position); 
 startActivity(intent); ??

Comment: Yes, when you want to start the new activity, just send the details and/or position in intent.put

Comment: I am not sure about the codes, just try if it works @Mocktheduck

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand well but you could use Intent for new Window For example:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));

   Intent intent=new Intent(ListItemActivity.this, newDetailActivity.class);  //newDetailActivity is a Activity you need to create or can say redirect window
 startActivity(intent);  // This opens a window
}
```

Here's Official Documentation for more information [Follow Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: But I have let's say 1000 items. How do I show the information? What is in newDetailActivity and how does it know which item I selected?

Comment: For your best practice with, you can try creating a new project and select Master/Details Flow instead of Empty Activity, where there's a full code and working model. This is what you exactly mean. Learn and then implement intro your code!!

Answer (score 1):

You can start a common activity and pass the selected item along with the intent :

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));

    //DetailsActivity is the activity which shows the extra details
    Intent intent=new Intent(ListItemActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);  

    //Add the item that the user clicked on, the class has to implement Parcelable or Serializable
    intent.putExtra("data", sweets.getItem(position));
    startActivity(intent);  // This opens a window
}
```

In the opened activity, you can get the item from the intent and display it's contents :

```
//in newDetailActivity :
Sweet s = getIntent().getExtras.getParcelable("data");
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of passing data between activities is using intents.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

     Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, i1.class);
     newActivity.putExtra("id", postion);
     newActivity.putExtra("key", value);        
     startActivity(newActivity);

    }
```

In short, putExtra method takes a key and value
which can be retrieved in the destination Activity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String id,key;
    if(extras == null) {
        id = null;
        key = null; 
    } else {
        id= extras.getString("id");
        key= extras.getString("key");
    }
```

Comment: and how to I add the onItemCLick method to my adapter?

Comment: Adapter are the bridge between you data and your view.  you want to set the listener on your listview instance